# Disabling a Button

Tags: input-forms

How can I disable a button after a user clicks it once ?

The current input I have is

```
{"File 1", FileNameSetter[Dynamic[b1],"Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" - {"*.csv"}}]}
```

This lets them upload a file, I can not figure how to disable the button after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should initialize your variables, if you do initialize with something that can be easily discriminated from a valid filename then disabling is quite simple:

```
b1=Null;
FileNameSetter[
  Dynamic[b1], "Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" -> {"*.csv"}}, 
  Enabled -> Dynamic[b1 === Null]]
```

(it seems odd to use the file name extension .csv for "Mathematica Notebook" files, are you sure that is intended?)

Comment: Yes it was intended, I actually have another question is it easier to use .exe files or .csv files to do calculations in mathematica?

Comment: @user38498: I don't understand how an .exe (typically an executable program) and a .csv (comma separated values file format for tabular data) could replace one another? An executable can be used to do part of calculations outside of Mathematica, but .csv could only be used to store and load data you need for your calculation or generate with it. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to take the information from excel files or .csv files and do calculations and have a output on mathematica

Comment: @user38498: Ah, ok then the question makes more sense: xls/xlsx vs. csv. I don't  think it is easy to give general advice for xls/xlsx vs. csv. I think both can be imported reasonably well in Mathematica, at least for "standard" content, that is not very large, only numbers and strings etc. It should be easy to test whether your data can be imported in either format and how long that tests...

Comment: Thank you! I have two column with 200 lines of data so not too much at all.

Comment: if the data is just numeric values I think either would work well. I guess that csv is probably somewhat faster to load (importing excel has somewhat more overhead, especially for the first import in a session)...

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Albert's code that does not require initialization:

```
FileNameSetter[Dynamic[b1], "Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" -> {"*.csv"}}, 
  Enabled -> Dynamic[! ValueQ @ b1]
]
```

Comment: but that would start disabled if `b1` happend to have a value, for whatever reason. To be more robust one could test for something like: `StringQ[b1]&&DirectoryQ[DirectoryName[b1]]`, which would also keep the button enabled if the user cancelles the file choose dialog. I think the most robust solution would be to use that test and still initialize with something well defined :-).

Comment: @Albert I voted for your answer and I acknowledge the points you make.  Nevertheless I like to play with alternatives. :^)

Comment: my comment wasn't meant as critizism: when I saw your answer I just was seeing advantages (concerning robustness and flexibility) if one would not restict the check to an exact match of the initial value as I did. Of course your solution also has the advantage fo being shorter, but I wouldn't trade that for robustness. Concerning that I noticed that you'd actually need something like `TrueQ@Quiet@DirectoryQ@DirectoryName[b1]` as `DirectoryQ` doesn't comply with the usual `*Q` function conventions as it gives a message and returns unevaluated in certain cases...